# Как вернуть голос пользователю?

Tags: python, pycord

В боте дискорда есть команда `user.timeout()`. Она отправляет пользователя подумать о своем поведении (если кратко, то мутит). Подскажите, пожалуйста, какая команда, чтобы вернуть голос пользователю? (Если кратно, то размутить).
Или придется делать через мут до времени "Сейчас"?:

```py
user.timeout(until = datetime.datetime.utcnow())
```

Comment: ничего не понятно

Comment: Имеется ввиду команда для бота дискорда. В дискорде имеется команда: user.timeout(). Мне нужна обратная ей

Comment: Что означает "команда, обратная user.timeout"? Опишите подробнее, что она должна делать? Вся необходимая информация должна быть в самом вопросе, добавить недостающую информацию можно по кнопке [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1512052/edit) под вопросом.

Comment: Дополнил, спасибо за замечание

Comment: Из документации: Параметр `until` — Дата и время ожидания пользователя. Если передать `None`, то пользователь удаляется из тайм-аута.

Comment: denisnumb, спасибо!